# Changing default settings for the Save Vector Layer as... dialogue box - QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, mac

I would like to change the defaults selected in the Save Vector Layer as... dialogue box.  I use export to kml and Shapefile daily and would like it to default to the settings I use, rather than changing them every time.  Is there a way to do this?

I am using QGIS 3.14.1 Pi for Mac and QGIS 3.10.10 A Coruna for Windows.

[image: Save Vector Layer dialogue box]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that you can preform,

1. create a user profile by going to `settings > user profiles > new profile`
2. then update or customize the `settings > options` for your liking,

**Example like -**

**CRS**

Select most prefeed CRS for projects and layers from the drop down and select

- CRS for projects as `use default CRS`
- CRS for layers as `Use default CRS layers`

[image]

with this you can customize the QGIS for your most of the likings with removing burden of doing the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on my question.  I think what I am looking for is the equivalent of your example of CRS settings but for the "Save Vector as" dialogue box - I can't find anywhere to edit these in Settings>Options. Once I can find where those defaults are set, I thought for sure I could save them to a user profile, as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3.32.3-Lima, select →**Settings** →**Options** →**Processing** →**General**, and select the *Default output vector layer extension*.

In that dialog box, you will find the *shp* and *kml* formats that fit your daily workflow. You'll need to pick one of those.

[image: QGIS - Settings - Options - Processing - General - Default output vector layer extension]